# analytical Lab Conundrum

Tags: organic-chemistry

We have a need for the following types of analysis.  I am not sure what analytical devices would be most suited to the needs.  I'm considering FT-IR and Ion Chromatography.  What do you think?

For the analysis of oil we require the following:

1. An analytical device to measure TBN total base number.
2. An analytical device that can measure the additive metals.

For the coolant:

1. I want to make sure  that in addition to determining chlorides, sulfates, glycolates, nitrates, phosphates, etc.  we also have a requirement to measure Reserve alkalinity under ASTM D 1121.

I look forward to any help you can give.